# Pandas compare columns and consider NULLS equal

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I used Pandas to joined two dataframes together and want to compare if column values are equal.

However, whenever I encounter NULLs (or NA ?) values, my comparison returns `False`

```
import pandas as pd

# create test dataframes
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'key': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'field1': ['foo', pd.NA, None, None, 6]})
df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'pk': [1, 2, 3, 4, 6], 'field2': ['foo', pd.NA, pd.NA, None, 6.0]})

# left join
df_joined = df_1.merge(df_2, 'left', left_on='key', right_on='pk')

# calculate comparison field
df_joined['compare'] = df_joined['field1'] == df_joined['field2']

print(df_joined)
```

yields

```
   key field1  pk field2  compare
0    1    foo   1    foo     True
1    2   <NA>   2   <NA>    False
2    3   None   3   None    False
3    4   <NA>   4   None    False
4    5     10   5   10.0     True
```

I want all values in `compare` to be `True`.

I know this could be accomplished with functions and Pandas `apply`, but I was hoping for a nice one line comparison similar to what I have already in the example.

Comment: edit: added in <NA> and None values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Andrej + Paul's are more concise than mine, but don't return true if one value is **None** and the other is **pd.NA**. If you would like that to also return true...

```
df_joined['compare'] = (df_joined['field1'] == df_joined['field2']) | (df_joined['field1'].isnull() & df_joined['field2'].isnull())

print(df_joined)
```

Prints

```
   key field1  pk field2  compare
0    1    foo   1    foo     True
1    2    bar   2    bar     True
2    3    baz   3    baz     True
3    4   None   4   <NA>     True
```

I had also changed the df with...

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'key': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'field1': ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', None]})
df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'pk': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'field2': ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', pd.NA]})
```

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution:

```
df2 = df_joined[['field1', 'field2']].dropna(how = 'all')
df_joined['compare'] = pd.NA
df_joined.update(df2.assign(compare = df2.field1.eq(df2.field2)))
df_joined['compare'] = df_joined['compare'].fillna(True)
```

Output:

```
   key field1  pk field2  compare
0    1    foo   1    foo     True
1    2   <NA>   2   <NA>     True
2    3   None   3   <NA>     True
3    4   None   4   None     True
4    5      6   5    6.0     True
```

---

A possible solution for the *previous* question:

```
df_joined.assign(compare = df_joined.field1.eq(df_joined.field2))
```

Output:

```
   key field1  pk field2  compare
0    1    foo   1    foo     True
1    2    bar   2    bar     True
2    3    baz   3    baz     True
3    4   None   4   None     True
```